# In Sockets, how to remove the length prefix in Socket Packet Protocol

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Code-wise, how do you remove the length prefix in SocketPacketProtocol.cs for [Nito.Async](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/) and/or [PacketProtcol](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html) for ordinary Sockets?

Comment: Adding length prefix to data is a good approach to implementing robust network exchange. Can you elaborate why exactly you want to remove it?

Comment: @elder_george the existing system that I connect to is maintained by a third party and doesn't have length prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your packets are fixed-size, then you can adapt PacketProtocol very easily.

If this is not the case, you'll have to roll your own solution. Nito.Async heavily relies on a length prefix to build a packet out of several "fragmented receives". If your protocol relies on other packet-delimitation methods i.e special sequence value, you'll have to change a lot of code.